# How to implement webRTC for iOS mobile app creating 1 to 1 Call (Video and Audio)?

Tags: ios, node.js, webrtc

I am developing an iOS Video application with webRTC, I have developed application for room video call as i got a demo named AppRTC.

But the problem is, we can connect if and only if we know the room name.

Any help and suggestion for creating 1-1 Video with webRTC.

Actually, i am not getting the proper way to create Signaling between two users.
I want to develop video call like Whatsapp,facebook and Hangout one to one video call.

I have followed this [AppRTC Demo Code On GitHub](https://github.com/inspiraluna/AppRTC-iOS) demo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a WhatsApp-style video call between two users using the "room" approach behind the scenes.

- Let's say that User 1 wants to call User 2.
- The app running on User 1's device generates a random room name and joins that room.
- User 1's app also communicates the room name to User 2's device.
- The app on User 2's device shows an incoming call alert.
- If User 2 taps the Answer button, the app joins the room and the call with User 1 starts.
- The actual room name used for the call doesn't need to be shown to any of the users.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create 1 to 1 video call you should build your own signaling mechanism.
What I mean by signaling mechanism is basically sending SDPs to each other.

You can find some useful info [here](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Getting-started-with-WebRTC-on-iOS/)